# Small italic text under section name?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, footnotes

I would like to write a small-font, italic comment right underneath a section name. Something like:

```
\section{First Section}
\comment{Some comment goes here.}
Here section text begins.
```

Is there a package or command to do that?

Comment: It should be fairly simple, but we need some details (document class what font size for the comment, must it be considered apecial part of the title, and so on).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. 

You could try with `\textit` (for Italic) and `\footnotesize` (small-font) or any other font commands, for example: `\textit{\footnotesize Some comment goes here.}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple command that does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\comment}[1]{\hspace{4em}{\small\textit{#1}}\bigskip\par}

\begin{document}
    \section{First Section}
    \comment{Some comment goes here.}
    Here section text begins.
\end{document}
```

The \hspace{4em} indents it under the section, the \small reduces the size (note the brackets surrounding it), the \textit makes it italic, and the \bigskip\par adds space after it.

Comment: This is almost what I need! Is there a way to make it appear closer to the section name? Right now the space between the comment and the section name is the same as between comment and section text. I'd like to move the comment up a bit if possible.

Comment: Added `\vspace{-1em}` right before `\hspace` and it worked like a charm!